# CSRFGuard 3 on jsp - error "required token is missing from the request " is always thrown

Tags: token, csrf, guard, required

I had configured CSRFGuard3 on JSP,Servlets 2.3 based webproject which I am running on RSA, Websphere appserver (in dev. env.). I had done exactly as specified in user guide. Placed CSRFGuard.jar in class path, csrfgaurd.properties and csrfguard.js under WEB-INF folder . In Web.xml done JavaScriptServlet mapping and other all other mapping as specified in guide.

My Requirment is to add protect few pages(not all) from this CSRF. 
So under filter mapping I had specified only those servlets and kept the JavaScriptServlet tag in the respective.jsp files.
For example for protecting travelpage.jsp & travledetailPage.jsp, where navigation is as follows   homepage.jsp-->travelpage.jsp -->travledetailPage.jsp

I then homepage.jsp & travelpage.jsp jsp pages I had put following tag

```
        <script src="JavaScriptServlet"></script>
```

And in web.xml  had done filter mapping as follows

```
     <filter>
  <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
<Servlet-name>travePageServlet</servlet-name>
</filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
   <Servlet-name>travledetailPageServlet</servlet-name>
 </filter>
```

But when I navigate in to the travel page, Error message is thrown by CSRF guard saying " Required token is missing from the request" and redirected error page.

Comment: After checking thoroughly I found out that the problem is with buttons. Links (a:href ) are working fine. I am always getting this error when I use button-submit and action specified in form tag.         I had also added <input hidden csrf token and crsftoken value > after importing taglib. but still no use.

Comment: did you ever get past the "required token is missing from the request" message? I'm also getting the same message